# Disable auto rotate in paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, image-rotation

I'm using Paperclip in my project but some of my users are complaining that it's incorrectly rotating some images.

For some reasons I can't even imagine I figured it out that some files are with wrong exif orientation attributes. I was looking and I saw that paperclip calls ImageMagick by default using `-auto-orient`. I saw that [the Thumbnail processor has an option to turn auto-orient on or off](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/ece46f46e9b9c327ee65402f6510557f1fca2ed1/lib/paperclip/thumbnail.rb#L40).

But I couldn't find a way to pass this to the Processor.

This is the code I have:

```
  has_attached_file :photo,
    styles: { :square => "400x400#" }
```

Does anyone now how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I created a new processor which extends from the paperclip default Thumbnail processor to send the correct options.

```
class WithouAutoOrientProcessor < Paperclip::Thumbnail
  def initialize(file, options = {}, attachment = nil)
    options[:auto_orient] = false
    super
  end
end
```

And in the model I added

```
  has_attached_file :photo,
    styles: { :square => "400x400#" },
    processors: [:WithouAutoOrientProcessor]
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it is a valid option to add your own processor, this is how you pass the option to the processor:

- In your `styles` hash replace your dimension strings with another hash
- Put your old dimensions in the key `geometry` into this hash
- The other key/value pairs are the options passed to the processor
- You can of course pass `auto_orient: false`, too

Applying this to your model's code:

```
has_attached_file :photo,
    styles: { square: { geometry: "400x400#", auto_orient: false } }
```